# xlwings/quandl import error in Python 3.6: can't import quandl with RunPython()

Tags: xlwings, quandl

Having a problem with xlwings Excel interface and quandl.
When using xlwings via the RunPython and trying to load a module that contains "import quandl", I get an error saying that there is "no module named quandl".
I can import quandl perfectly when running my Python code directly in Pycharm but also from xlwings in UDF call form. The latter doesn't suit my needs unfortunately.

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub and attach a sample to replicate the issue.

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed. In addition to my standard "conda install quandl", I also ran "pip install quandl" which apparently solved the problem. Never had to that before with any other package but at least I'm good.